# Implementing ActionbarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to implement SherlockActionbar. I downloaded the project from GitHub and imported the library as a Project and using Android 2.2 as the base SDK.

But the Project seems to have a lot of errors.

Guess i need to import some other library.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compile with Android 3.2. The library needs access to classes from the Honeycomb SDK in order to support it when run on 3.0+

Despite compiling with the newer SDK, you can still support back to Android 2.2 by setting the `minSdkVersion` to '8'.

Each of the samples in the repository (for version 3) support back to Android 1.6. Take a look at [their sources](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/tree/master/samples) for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks :) that worked. When i add the Project as Lib to my project now i get the following error. http://i.imgur.com/ZTCU4.jpg

Comment: Your project also needs to be built with Android 3.2 (or in your case, Google Maps API 13).